# How to download files from ftp to local directory using C#?

Tags: ftp, webclient, credentials, transfer

hi i am using the following code but it giving an error

```
 using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
        {
            ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            ftpClient.DownloadFile("ftp://path.com/Business Plan.docx", "D:\\Folder\test.docx");
        }
```

but i am getting an error **illegal characters in path**.

I am not understanding how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This string:

```
"D:\\Folder\test.docx"
```

Is treating the slashes ('`\`') as escape characters - use this instead:

```
@"D:\Folder\test.docx"
```

Or (more messy), double escape to be treated as a literal slash:

```
"D:\\Folder\\test.docx"
```

Comment: If you use the `@` prefix then you should also remove the extra \ before 'folder'